# Can't figure out whats the cause of seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Total C noob here. Having difficulty location the cause of this seg fault. I have tried running a debugger the `GBD` debugger but I can't figure out how to get it working. The function I'm trying to test removes the contents of an array, puts it in a linked list and then puts the values of the linked list into the second array given to the function. Heres my test and function code.

#### Test

```
int test_transfer(void) {
    #define ARRAY_LENGTH 10
    void *arr1[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
        arr1[i] = &i;
    }

    void *ptr;
    void *arr2[ARRAY_LENGTH];
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
        arr2[i] = ptr;
    }

    transfer(arr1, arr2, ARRAY_LENGTH, sizeof(int), add_to_front, remove_from_front);

    for (int i=0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", *((int *)arr2[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Transfer Function

```
void transfer(void **arr1, void **arr2, int length, int size, void (*insert)(List *, void *), void* (*remove)(List *)) {
    List *list = List_create();

    for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
        (*insert)(list, &arr1[i]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
        void *indexPtr = arr2 + i*size;
        indexPtr = (*remove)(list);
    }

}
```

Comment: your code has UB all over the place. Using the value of a pointer to a variable that's gone out of scope; reading the value of an uninitialized pointer, for example.

Comment: You need to ***study*** the language, not guess it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is plagued with bugs, and there's no single issue to answer about.

Comment: I'm still stuck on the sense of purposely populating an array of `void*`, that being `arr2` with the value of an indeterminate pointer `ptr`

Comment: I'm trying to create an empty of `void *`

Answer (score 1):

In this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
    arr1[i] = &i;
}
```

you make each element in `arr1` point to the *local* variable `i`, and when I say local I don't mean local in the function, but local in the scope of the *loop*.

The above loop is roughly equivalent to

```
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
        arr1[i] = &i;
    }
}
```

Once the loop is over, the variable `i` goes out of scope and no longer exists, leaving you with lots of stray pointers, and when you try to dereference these pointers you will have *undefined behavior*.

Also note that all elements in the array `arr1` are initialized to point to the *same* location.

---

You have a different problem for the second array `arr2`, where you make all pointers in the array equal to the *uninitialized* pointer `ptr`. Uninitialized local variables have an *indeterminate* value, and using them before they are initialized *also* leads to undefined behavior.

---

Finally, in the `transfer` function you have the statement

```
void *indexPtr = arr2 + i*size;
```

Without knowing what `remove` is or what it does, the expression `arr2 + anything` will give you a pointer to a specific element in the array, and since every element is in turn a pointer what you get is a pointer to a pointer, of type `void **`.

Comment: Should I copy the value of `i` to a variable thats outside the scope of the `for` loop? For `arry2` how can I create an empty array of pointers?

Comment: @DanielKobe In C you can never have an *empty* array. And array of X elements will always have X elements. Exactly what should be done here I don't know since I have no idea that the code is supposed to do, or what all the functions you aren't showing are doing.

Comment: For the `arr1` can you should the correct way fill an array with the values of `i` in the `for` loop?

Comment: @DanielKobe It's an array of *pointers*, you can't fill it with values. To do that you need to make it an array of *values*, like e.g. `int arr1[ARRAY_LENGTH];`

Comment: can you do an array of `void *` values and type cast those to `ints` later. Im trying to have my function accept multiple different typed arrays?